# Building Yield Curve using different instruments

Tags: yield-curve

I'm trying to back out the LIBOR curves on Bloomberg. And I am using exactly the same instruments as BBG, i.e. 3-month LIBOR, followed by 6 EuroDollar Futures contracts (ED1, ..., ED6), and finally the swaps. The overall shape and magnitude of my curve is correct, however, for the zero rates at last two futures contracts and the first swap, there are big jumps. So my question is how does BBG remove or smoothen such jumps in their curve?

Comment: I'd first check, are you using the same convexity adjustment as Bbg?

Comment: @DimitriVulis I did not use convexity adjustment at this moment, so I switched off the cvx adj in BBG but it did not give me a very different curve..

Comment: Are your jumps on the zero rates or forwards? Jumps on zero rates would be strange. If its forwards, check your settings for the interpolation method. I believe the default would be "Smooth Forward (Cont) which is done by a global pricing method. If you are using linear interpolation  of zeros, jumps would be expected on short forward rates around the nodes.

Comment: @David Duarte my jumps were on the zero rates, that’s why I’m so confused. But based on the quoted price of futures and swaps, there are such jumps. I don’t think the solved zero rates should deviate much from the implied rates from quoted price. So I want to ask if anyone knows how BBG deal with such jumps.

Comment: What kind of jumps are we talking about? For which date are you building the USD Curve?

Comment: Nah, I fixed the problem. Thx anyway!